# Failed to build iOS app Error output from Xcode build:

Tags: xcode, flutter, flutter-ios

I upgraded my flutter version to

```
Flutter 1.24.0-10.2.pre • channel beta • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 022b333a08 (3 days ago) • 2020-11-18 11:35:09 -0800
Engine • revision 07c1eed46b
Tools • Dart 2.12.0 (build 2.12.0-29.10.beta)
```

My project was working good, but after upgrading, I am facing bellow errors while trying to run in simulator!

```
  Xcode build done.                                           19.8s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    2020-11-21 15:26:17.268 xcodebuild[20177:312988] warning:  The file reference for "Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Models/TOActivityCroppedImageProvider.h" is a member of multiple groups
    ("TOCropViewController" and "TOCropViewController"); this indicates a malformed project.  Only the membership in one of the groups will be preserved (but membership in targets will be unaffected).  If you
    want a reference to the same file in more than one group, please add another reference to the same path.
    2020-11-21 15:26:17.268 xcodebuild[20177:312988] warning:  The file reference for "Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Views/TOCropOverlayView.h" is a member of multiple groups ("TOCropViewController" and
    "TOCropViewController"); this indicates a malformed project.  Only the membership in one of the groups will be preserved (but membership in targets will be unaffected).  If you want a reference to the same
    file in more than one group, please add another reference to the same path.
    2020-11-21 15:26:17.268 xcodebuild[20177:312988] warning:  The file reference for "Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Models/TOCroppedImageAttributes.h" is a member of multiple groups ("TOCropViewController"
    and "TOCropViewController"); this indicates a malformed project.  Only the membership in one of the groups will be preserved (but membership in targets will be unaffected).  If you want a reference to the
    same file in more than one group, please add another reference to the same path.
    2020-11-21 15:26:17.268 xcodebuild[20177:312988] warning:  The file reference for "Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Views/TOCropScrollView.h" is a member of multiple groups ("TOCropViewController" and
    "TOCropViewController"); this indicates a malformed project.  Only the membership in one of the groups will be preserved (but membership in targets will be unaffected).  If you want a reference to the same
    file in more than one group, please add another reference to the same path.
    2020-11-21 15:26:17.268 xcodebuild[20177:312988] warning:  The file reference for "Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Views/TOCropToolbar.h" is a member of multiple groups ("TOCropViewController" and
    "TOCropViewController"); this indicates a malformed project.  Only the membership in one of the groups will be preserved (but membership in targets will be unaffected).  If you want a reference to the same
    file in more than one group, please add another reference to the same path.
    2020-11-21 15:26:17.268 xcodebuild[20177:312988] warning:  The file reference for "Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Views/TOCropView.h" is a member of multiple groups ("TOCropViewController" and
    "TOCropViewController"); this indicates a malformed project.  Only the membership in one of the groups will be preserved (but membership in targets will be unaffected).  If you want a reference to the same
    file in more than one group, please add another reference to the same path.
    2020-11-21 15:26:17.268 xcodebuild[20177:312988] warning:  The file reference for "Objective-C/TOCropViewController/TOCropViewController.h" is a member of multiple groups ("TOCropViewController" and
    "TOCropViewController"); this indicates a malformed project.  Only the membership in one of the groups will be preserved (but membership in targets will be unaffected).  If you want a reference to the same
    file in more than one group, please add another reference to the same path.
    2020-11-21 15:26:17.268 xcodebuild[20177:312988] warning:  The file reference for "Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Models/TOCropViewControllerTransitioning.h" is a member of multiple groups
    ("TOCropViewController" and "TOCropViewController"); this indicates a malformed project.  Only the membership in one of the groups will be preserved (but membership in targets will be unaffected).  If you
    want a reference to the same file in more than one group, please add another reference to the same path.
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    In file included from /Users/mdzainalabedin/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging-7.0.0/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseMessagingPlugin.m:9:
    /Users/mdzainalabedin/padelmatchv2/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/Firebase/Firebase.h:75:10: warning: "FirebaseAnalytics.framework is not included in your target. Please add `Firebase/Analytics` to your Podfile or
    add FirebaseAnalytics.framework to your project to ensure Firebase Messaging works as intended." [-W#warnings]
            #warning "FirebaseAnalytics.framework is not included in your target. Please add \
             ^
    /Users/mdzainalabedin/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging-7.0.0/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseMessagingPlugin.m:190:43: warning: 'FIRMessagingRemoteMessage' is deprecated: FCM direct channel is
    deprecated, please use APNs for downstream message handling. [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    - (void)applicationReceivedRemoteMessage:(FIRMessagingRemoteMessage *)remoteMessage {
                                              ^
    In file included from /Users/mdzainalabedin/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging-7.0.0/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseMessagingPlugin.m:9:
    In file included from /Users/mdzainalabedin/padelmatchv2/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/Firebase/Firebase.h:72:
    In file included from /Users/mdzainalabedin/padelmatchv2/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/FirebaseMessaging/FirebaseMessaging.h:17:
    /Users/mdzainalabedin/padelmatchv2/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/FirebaseMessaging/FIRMessaging.h:219:1: note: 'FIRMessagingRemoteMessage' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    __deprecated_msg(
    ^
    In module 'Foundation' imported from /Users/mdzainalabedin/padelmatchv2/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/FirebaseCore/FIRApp.h:17:
    In module 'CoreFoundation' imported from
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:6:
    In module 'Darwin' imported from
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h:16:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.2.sdk/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:200:48: note: expanded from macro '__deprecated_msg'
            #define __deprecated_msg(_msg) __attribute__((__deprecated__(_msg)))
                                                          ^
    /Users/mdzainalabedin/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging-7.0.0/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseMessagingPlugin.m:290:24: warning: 'FIRMessagingRemoteMessage' is deprecated: FCM direct channel is
    deprecated, please use APNs for downstream message handling. [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        didReceiveMessage:(FIRMessagingRemoteMessage *)remoteMessage {
                           ^
    In file included from /Users/mdzainalabedin/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging-7.0.0/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseMessagingPlugin.m:9:
    In file included from /Users/mdzainalabedin/padelmatchv2/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/Firebase/Firebase.h:72:
    In file included from /Users/mdzainalabedin/padelmatchv2/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/FirebaseMessaging/FirebaseMessaging.h:17:
    /Users/mdzainalabedin/padelmatchv2/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/FirebaseMessaging/FIRMessaging.h:219:1: note: 'FIRMessagingRemoteMessage' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    __deprecated_msg(
    ^
    In module 'Foundation' imported from /Users/mdzainalabedin/padelmatchv2/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/FirebaseCore/FIRApp.h:17:
    In module 'CoreFoundation' imported from
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:6:
    In module 'Darwin' imported from
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h:16:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.2.sdk/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:200:48: note: expanded from macro '__deprecated_msg'
            #define __deprecated_msg(_msg) __attribute__((__deprecated__(_msg)))
                                                          ^
    /Users/mdzainalabedin/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging-7.0.0/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseMessagingPlugin.m:136:30: warning: 'shouldEstablishDirectChannel' is deprecated: FCM direct channel is
    deprecated, please use APNs channel for downstream message delivery. [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        [FIRMessaging messaging].shouldEstablishDirectChannel = true;
                                 ^
    In file included from /Users/mdzainalabedin/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging-7.0.0/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseMessagingPlugin.m:9:
    In file included from /Users/mdzainalabedin/padelmatchv2/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/Firebase/Firebase.h:72:
    In file included from /Users/mdzainalabedin/padelmatchv2/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/FirebaseMessaging/FirebaseMessaging.h:17:
    /Users/mdzainalabedin/padelmatchv2/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/FirebaseMessaging/FIRMessaging.h:283:56: note: 'shouldEstablishDirectChannel' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    @property(nonatomic) BOOL shouldEstablishDirectChannel DEPRECATED_MSG_ATTRIBUTE(
                                                           ^
    In module 'Foundation' imported from /Users/mdzainalabedin/padelmatchv2/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/FirebaseCore/FIRApp.h:17:
    In module 'CoreFoundation' imported from
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:6:
    In module 'Darwin' imported from
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h:16:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.2.sdk/usr/include/AvailabilityMacros.h:182:64: note: expanded from macro
    'DEPRECATED_MSG_ATTRIBUTE'
                #define DEPRECATED_MSG_ATTRIBUTE(s) __attribute__((deprecated(s)))
                                                                   ^
    /Users/mdzainalabedin/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging-7.0.0/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseMessagingPlugin.m:191:52: warning: 'appData' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
      [self didReceiveRemoteNotification:remoteMessage.appData];
                                                       ^
    In file included from /Users/mdzainalabedin/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging-7.0.0/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseMessagingPlugin.m:9:
    In file included from /Users/mdzainalabedin/padelmatchv2/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/Firebase/Firebase.h:72:
    In file included from /Users/mdzainalabedin/padelmatchv2/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/FirebaseMessaging/FirebaseMessaging.h:17:
    /Users/mdzainalabedin/padelmatchv2/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/FirebaseMessaging/FIRMessaging.h:226:62: note: 'appData' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    @property(nonatomic, readonly, strong) NSDictionary *appData DEPRECATED_ATTRIBUTE;
                                                                 ^
    In module 'Foundation' imported from /Users/mdzainalabedin/padelmatchv2/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/FirebaseCore/FIRApp.h:17:
    In module 'CoreFoundation' imported from
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:6:
    In module 'Darwin' imported from
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h:16:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.2.sdk/usr/include/AvailabilityMacros.h:180:60: note: expanded from macro 'DEPRECATED_ATTRIBUTE'
            #define DEPRECATED_ATTRIBUTE        __attribute__((deprecated))
                                                               ^
    /Users/mdzainalabedin/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging-7.0.0/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseMessagingPlugin.m:289:1: warning: implementing deprecated method [-Wdeprecated-implementations]
    - (void)messaging:(FIRMessaging *)messaging
    ^
    In file included from /Users/mdzainalabedin/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging-7.0.0/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseMessagingPlugin.m:9:
    In file included from /Users/mdzainalabedin/padelmatchv2/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/Firebase/Firebase.h:72:
    In file included from /Users/mdzainalabedin/padelmatchv2/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/FirebaseMessaging/FirebaseMessaging.h:17:
    /Users/mdzainalabedin/padelmatchv2/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/FirebaseMessaging/FIRMessaging.h:253:1: note: method 'messaging:didReceiveMessage:' declared here
    - (void)messaging:(FIRMessaging *)messaging
    ^
    /Users/mdzainalabedin/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging-7.0.0/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseMessagingPlugin.m:291:63: warning: 'appData' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
      [_channel invokeMethod:@"onMessage" arguments:remoteMessage.appData];
                                                                  ^
    In file included from /Users/mdzainalabedin/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging-7.0.0/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseMessagingPlugin.m:9:
    In file included from /Users/mdzainalabedin/padelmatchv2/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/Firebase/Firebase.h:72:
    In file included from /Users/mdzainalabedin/padelmatchv2/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/FirebaseMessaging/FirebaseMessaging.h:17:
    /Users/mdzainalabedin/padelmatchv2/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/FirebaseMessaging/FIRMessaging.h:226:62: note: 'appData' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    @property(nonatomic, readonly, strong) NSDictionary *appData DEPRECATED_ATTRIBUTE;
                                                                 ^
    In module 'Foundation' imported from /Users/mdzainalabedin/padelmatchv2/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/FirebaseCore/FIRApp.h:17:
    In module 'CoreFoundation' imported from
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:6:
    In module 'Darwin' imported from
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h:16:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.2.sdk/usr/include/AvailabilityMacros.h:180:60: note: expanded from macro 'DEPRECATED_ATTRIBUTE'
            #define DEPRECATED_ATTRIBUTE        __attribute__((deprecated))
                                                               ^
    7 warnings generated.
    error: Build input file cannot be found: '/Users/mdzainalabedin/Downloads/GoogleService-Info.plist' (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'GoogleDataTransport' from project
    'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'sqflite' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'url_launcher' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'shared_preferences' from project
    'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'path_provider' from project
    'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'launch_review' from project
    'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'image_picker' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'image_cropper' from project
    'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'firebase_messaging' from project
    'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'firebase_core' from project
    'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'connectivity' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target
    'TOCropViewController-TOCropViewControllerBundle' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'FirebaseCore' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'FirebaseMessaging' from project
    'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'FirebaseInstallations' from
    project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'FirebaseInstanceID' from project
    'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'FirebaseAnalyticsInterop' from
    project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'Protobuf' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'TOCropViewController' from project
    'Pods')
    warning: Skipping duplicate build file in Copy Headers build phase: /Users/mdzainalabedin/padelmatchv2/ios/Pods/TOCropViewController/Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Models/TOActivityCroppedImageProvider.h
    (in target 'TOCropViewController' from project 'Pods')
    warning: Skipping duplicate build file in Copy Headers build phase: /Users/mdzainalabedin/padelmatchv2/ios/Pods/TOCropViewController/Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Views/TOCropOverlayView.h (in target
    'TOCropViewController' from project 'Pods')
    warning: Skipping duplicate build file in Copy Headers build phase: /Users/mdzainalabedin/padelmatchv2/ios/Pods/TOCropViewController/Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Models/TOCroppedImageAttributes.h (in
    target 'TOCropViewController' from project 'Pods')
    warning: Skipping duplicate build file in Copy Headers build phase: /Users/mdzainalabedin/padelmatchv2/ios/Pods/TOCropViewController/Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Views/TOCropScrollView.h (in target
    'TOCropViewController' from project 'Pods')
    warning: Skipping duplicate build file in Copy Headers build phase: /Users/mdzainalabedin/padelmatchv2/ios/Pods/TOCropViewController/Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Views/TOCropToolbar.h (in target
    'TOCropViewController' from project 'Pods')
    warning: Skipping duplicate build file in Copy Headers build phase: /Users/mdzainalabedin/padelmatchv2/ios/Pods/TOCropViewController/Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Views/TOCropView.h (in target
    'TOCropViewController' from project 'Pods')
    warning: Skipping duplicate build file in Copy Headers build phase: /Users/mdzainalabedin/padelmatchv2/ios/Pods/TOCropViewController/Objective-C/TOCropViewController/TOCropViewController.h (in target
    'TOCropViewController' from project 'Pods')
    warning: Skipping duplicate build file in Copy Headers build phase: /Users/mdzainalabedin/padelmatchv2/ios/Pods/TOCropViewController/Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Models/TOCropViewControllerTransitioning.h
    (in target 'TOCropViewController' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'FirebaseCoreDiagnostics' from
    project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'FirebaseCoreDiagnosticsInterop'
    from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'Reachability' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'FMDB' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'GoogleUtilities' from project
    'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'Flutter' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'Firebase' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'Pods-Runner' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'PromisesObjC' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'nanopb' from project 'Pods')

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 11.
```

Any idea what's going on? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue after upgrading to `Flutter 1.22.4 stable channel` . It's now working good after doing this:

- `flutter clean`
- Delete `Podfile.lock` in iOS folder
- Checking packages updates
- `flutter run`

If these steps don't help; try to switch to the stable channel:

```
flutter channel stable
```

After switching remember to perform the steps above.

Comment: I tried to switch to stable but got errors.


Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    2 warnings generated.
    error: the following command failed with exit code 0 but produced no further output
    CompileC
    /Users/mdzainalabedin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bxqgriigtqxmjubjdimslcrcujux/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-

Comment: Try to delete even `Pods` folder and run it again!!

Comment: Unfortunately I keep getting errors 

Xcode's output:
↳
    While building module 'Flutter' imported from
    /Users/mdzainalabedin/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/url_launcher-5.5.0/
    ios/Classes/FLTURLLauncherPlugin.h:5:
    In file included from <module-includes>:1:
    In file included from
    /Users/mdzainalabedin/padelmatchv2/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/Headers/Flu
    tter.h:8:
    /Users/mdzainalabedin/padelmatchv2/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/Headers/Flu
    tterAppDelegate.h:10:10: warning: double-quoted include "FlutterMacros.h" in
    framework header, expect

Comment: Please remember to update packages ex: `url_launcher`, etc. after updating them run `flutter clean`

Comment: All of the packages using latest version :/